# Can't figure out why my collision check doesn't work

Tags: java

I've tried 3 different ways to check collision between the player and the bomb after it explodes. I've used a point obj with check bounds of the bomb with the players point, both player and bomb being rectangles and I've written a 4 line if statement to check all points for the player against those of the bomb.

I just put all my code below that would be useful. Also I'm using eclipse.

If you have any ideas to why it's still not working I'd gladly take them.
Thanks for all the help

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


/**
* Class Driver - write a description of the class here
* 
* @author (your name) 
* @version (a version number)
*/

public class Driver extends JApplet
private Timer timer= new Timer(10, null);
private Animation anime=new Animation(timer,500,500);

public void init()
{
    setSize(500,500);
    getContentPane().add(anime);
}

public void start()
{
  timer.start();   

}

public void stop()
{
    timer.stop();
}
}
```

/*****animation******/

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Animation extends JPanel {
private Timer timer;
private Map Map;
private BomberMen P1;
private BomberMen P2;
private int width;
private int height;
private HashSet<Bomb> bombs = new HashSet<Bomb>();
private HashSet<Wall> walls = new HashSet<Wall>();
private HashSet<Bomb> toRemove = new HashSet<Bomb>();
private int gamestate;
private Menu menu;

public Animation(Timer cd, int w, int h) {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    setFocusable(true);
    this.timer = cd;
    P1 = new BomberMen(450,450);
    P2 = new BomberMen(0,0);
    timer.addActionListener(new DrawerListener());
    addKeyListener(new UserKeyListener());
    this.gamestate=1;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
if (gamestate==1)
    {
        Menu.draw(g);
    }
 if (gamestate==2)
  {
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    P1.draw(g);
    P2.draw(g);
    for (Wall w : walls)
    {
        w.draw(g);
    }

    for (Bomb b : bombs)
    {
        b.draw(g);
    }
  }
 if (gamestate==3)
 {
     Menu.draw(g);
 }
}


private void MakeWalls() {
    for (int y = 0; y< 500; y += 60) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 200; x += 60) {
            walls.add(new Wall(x, y, 30, 30));
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkCollision() {

    for (Bomb b : bombs) {
        if (b.getExplode() == true) 
        { 

            if(P1.getBounds().intersects(b.getBoundsTall()) || P1.getBounds().intersects(b.getBoundsLong()))
            {
                return true;
            }

            else
            {
                return false;
            }






            /**
           if (P1.getX()>b.getX100() && P1.getX()<b.getX110() && P1.getY() > b.getY10() && P1.getY() < b.getY20() //top right point
            ||  P1.getX30()>b.getX100() && P1.getX30()<b.getX110() && P1.getY() > b.getY10() && P1.getY() < b.getY20() //top left point             
            ||  P1.getX30()>b.getX100() && P1.getX30()<b.getX110() && P1.getY30() > b.getY10() && P1.getY30() < b.getY20()  //bot left point
            ||  P1.getX()>b.getX100() && P1.getX()<b.getX110() && P1.getY30() > b.getY10() && P1.getY30() < b.getY20() //bot right point
                )
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        **/
            /**
            for (Point p : P1.getHitBox()) {
                if (b.getHitboxLong().contains(p) || b.getHitboxTall().contains(p)) 
                {
                    return true;
                }
                **/



        }
    }
    return false;
}

private class DrawerListener implements ActionListener {
    private int countdown = 0;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if (gamestate == 2) 
        {
            for (Bomb b : bombs)
            {
                b.update();
                if (b.getTime() >= 500)
                    toRemove.add(b);
            }
            bombs.removeAll(toRemove);
            toRemove = new HashSet<Bomb>();

            if (checkCollision() == true)
            {

                gamestate = 1;

            }
            repaint();
        }

    }

}

private class UserKeyListener implements KeyListener 
{

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (gamestate==1)
        {
            if(e.getKeyCode()==37)
            {
                gamestate=2;
            }
        }

    if(gamestate==2)
    {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 37) {//left
            P1.changeX(-30);
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == 38) {//up
            P1.changeY(-30);
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == 39) {//right
            P1.changeX(30);
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == 40) {//down
            P1.changeY(30);
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == 32) {//space
            bombs.add(new Bomb(P1.getX() + 10, P1.getY() + 10));

        }

        if(e.getKeyCode()==65)//left
        {
            P2.changeX(-30);
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==87)//up
        {
            P2.changeY(-30);
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==68)//right
        {
            P2.changeX(30);
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==83)//down
        {
            P2.changeY(30);
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==70)//F for bomb
        {
            bombs.add(new Bomb(P2.getX()+10,P2.getY()+10));
        }
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

}

/********Bomb***********/

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashSet;

    public class Bomb 
    {
      private int countdown;
      private int x;
      private int y;
      private boolean explode;
      private Rectangle hitboxTall;
      private Rectangle hitboxLong;

      public Bomb(int x,int y)
      {
          this.explode = false;
          this.countdown=0;
          this.x=x;
          this.y=y;

      }

      public void draw(Graphics g)
      {
          if(explode == true)
          {
              g.drawRect(x-100,y-10,210,30);//horizontal
              g.drawRect(x-10,y-100,30,210);//vertical
          }
          else if (explode == false)
              g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
      }

      public void update()
      {

         if (countdown == 300)
          {
             explode=true;
             hitboxLong = new Rectangle(x-100,y-10,210,30);//H
             hitboxTall = new Rectangle(x-10,y-100,30,210);//V

          }

         countdown++;
      }
      public int getTime()
      {
          return countdown;
      }
      public boolean getExplode()
      {
          return explode;
      }
    /**
    public Rectangle getHitboxTall() {
        return hitboxTall;
    }

    public void setHitboxTall(Rectangle hitboxTall) {
        this.hitboxTall = hitboxTall;
    }

    public Rectangle getHitboxLong() {
        return hitboxLong;
    }

    public void setHitboxLong(Rectangle hitboxLong) {
        this.hitboxLong = hitboxLong;
        }
    **/
    public int getX100()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return x-100;
    }
    public int getX110()
    {
        return x+110;
    }
    public int getY10()
    {
        return y-10;
    }
    public int getY20()
    {
        return y+20;    
    }

    public Rectangle getBoundsTall() {

        return hitboxTall.getBounds();
    }
    public Rectangle getBoundsLong()
    {
        return hitboxLong.getBounds();
    }

    }
```

/*************player***********/

```
        import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import javax.imageio.*;

    public class BomberMen
    {
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private BufferedImage img;
        private HashSet <Point> hitBox = new HashSet<Point>(); 
        private Point person;
        private Rectangle player; 

        public BomberMen(int x,int y)
        {
            this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
           player = new Rectangle(x,y,30,30);

        }

        public void update(int x,int y)
        {
            this.x+=x;
            this.y+=y;
        }

        public void changeX(int x)
        {
            update(x,0);

        }

        public void changeY(int y)
        {
            update(0,y);
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g)
        {  
        /** BufferedImage img = null;
          try {
                 img = ImageIO.read(new File("bombermanDude.jpg"));
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                  } 
              g.drawImage(img, 200, 200, null);
          **/ 

            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.drawRect(x,y,30,30);
        }
    /**
        public HashSet<Point> getHitBox() {
            return hitBox;
        }

        public void setHitBox(HashSet<Point> hitBox) {
            this.hitBox = hitBox;
        }

        public Point getPerson() {
            return person;
        }

        public void setPerson(Point person) {
            this.person = person;
        }

        private void fillSet()
        {
            hitBox.add(person);
            hitBox.add(new Point ((int) person.getX()+30, (int) person.getY()  ));
            hitBox.add(new Point ((int) person.getX()+30, (int) person.getY()+30));
            hitBox.add(new Point ((int) person.getX(),    (int) person.getY()+30));
        }
        **/
        public int getX() 
        {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY()
        {
            return y;
        }
        public int getX30()
        {
            return x+30;
        }
        public int getY30()
        {
            return y+30;
        }

        public Rectangle getBounds() 
        {
            return player.getBounds();

        }
    }
```

/**********menu**************/

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Menu extends JPanel
{
    private static Font myFont = new Font("Garamond",Font.BOLD,20);

    public static void draw(Graphics g)
    {   
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(0, 0,500,500);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.setFont(myFont);
        g.drawString("Start Game", 200, 200);
        g.drawString("Press Enter", 200, 250);

        //JButton b1 = new JButton("Start Game, Y or N");
        //b1.setMnemonic(y);
        //b1.

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    /**private class DrawerListener implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    //  if ()
    }
    **/
}
```

/************wall****************/
    import java.awt.*;

```
public class Wall 
{
private int h=30;
private int w=30;
private int x;
private int y;

public Wall(int x,int y,int h, int w)
{
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.h=h;
    this.w=w;
}

public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(x,y,30,30);
}

}
```

Comment: Would you also provide the code for the `Wall` class so we can compile and see the problem?

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: There you go.. Sorry about that.

Comment: Looks like you missed the key word **Minimal**...